# spinner is not displaying proper while adding blank row

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am displaying spinner in recyclerview row. when i add blank row using "Add Member" button, spinner display half like below image[image]

Please help me.i search on google but i didn't  get any solution
here is layout for this screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_numbertitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
        android:text="First Member"
        android:textColor="#424242"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_surname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_relation"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="35dp"
            android:entries="@array/relation"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_city"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="City"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is a layout for recyclerview row.when is filled data with array, spinner display proper spinner but when i add blank row, it display like below image

```
 <style name="ThemeSpinner">
    <!-- Color when pressed -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffa000</item>
    <!-- Default color for the dropdown arrow and line -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffc107</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

here is theme applied to the spinner

Comment: Can you post the layout file contents where you are using the spinner ?

Comment: i have posted layout file for the row

Comment: check if it helps after adding padding of 5dp to parent Linear Layout of the row , where spinner is placed.

Comment: but when i add prefill array it will display fine

Comment: Are you dynamically adding the options to choosed from spinner ?

Comment: No.i have set option into layout file

Comment: I literally created a sample project with your layout file, populated the spinner with a predefined array resource, it seemed to look fine after I ran it on emulator . What is the style that you have set for your spinner ?

Comment: Style used in spinner is android default style for underline below spinner.have you used this layout file in recylerview?

Comment: No haven't used within a RecyclerView , created a static layout file , what is the theme applied for spinner? Post the theme that you've applied for spinner

Comment: i have update theme in my question. have look at it

Comment: Create a gist of your code with all logic that you implemented, and post the link to that gist, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `layout_height` value to `wrap_content` .

If the custom background an xml drawable file check that you aren't using padding at the bottom.

Comment: both height and width attribute is wrap_content

Comment: i havn't use any kind of padding.when i set adapter to recyclerview, spinner display proper but when i add blank row using "Add Member", it display like this image